# struct x vs x_t in C

Tags: c, struct

In my recent operating systems class we have a bunch of objects defined as such:

```
typedef struct someobj {
  ... stuff ...
} someobj_t;
```

I know what that does just fine.

The question is that sometimes in the given support code the structs were refered to as `struct someobj *some`, and sometimes as `someobj_t *some`.  Is there an actual / useful reason to refer to structs in these two different ways, or is just a stylistic difference?

Comment: Are you sure you got the question right? `someobj_t` is an object, not a type, you might have omitted one single `typedef` in your code.

Comment: the `_t` notation, assuming you mean a typedef, if just a convention to distinguish `struct someobj` and `someobj` (assuming this was the typedef'd name) -- this is because C has two different "namespaces" for these (struct and typedef), and presumably this convention helps add semantics to the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming we're asking about the following code *(there's no `typedef` in the question as I'm writing, but I'm assuming it was meant to be there):*

```
typedef struct someobj {
    // content
} someobj_t;
```

Actually usually it'd be sufficient to omit the name `someobj` and use `someobj_t` consistently. However there's that situation when you want the struct to refer to itself:

```
typedef struct someobj {
    struct someobj* next;
    // cannot say someobj_t* yet - typedef not complete
} someobj_t;

// and from now on, both struct someobj and`someobj_t are equivalent
```

Answer (score 6):

While it's up to you whether you use a typedef or the struct name, there is a very good reason **not to use** `typedef` names ending in `_t`. All such names are reserved by POSIX for use by the implementation, and may refer to implementation-specific types or may be standardized in future versions of POSIX. Unfortunately many library authors ignore this.

Personally I prefer not to use `typedef` for structures, but if you do choose to use it, at least avoid the reserved namespace.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html (just providing a link to canonical source)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant:

```
typedef struct someobj
{
    /* ... */
} someobj_t;
```

the difference in general is just stylistic; some people prefer to stick to the "old C"-style naming for structs (where you have to put the `struct` keyword any time you're referring to that type), others like the more synthetic way of just using `someobj_t`.

Many people who use the symbol defined by the `typedef` feel it more natural because often they come from other languages (e.g. C++, C#, ...) where there's no need for the `struct` thing. In many cases they even omit the `struct` name from the declaration and just leave the `typedef`ed name.

The usage of those two symbols is in general equivalent, but there are some caveats; first of all, before the end of the `typedef` the `_t` version doesn't exist, so you cannot declare pointers to the structure inside itself using the `_t` name.

Then, the `typedef` "exists" only during the compilation; this means that the compiler and the debugger will refer to your symbol with the non-`typedef`ed name. If you use a `typedef` without a "real" structure name, when you have to investigate errors with some compilers/debuggers you may go mad because you can't refer to a "real" structure name, since `typedef`ed structures without a real name actually are anonymous structures.

This can become particularly problematic if you have to export your structure with MIDL and stuff like that; see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/27/8338530.aspx) by Raymond Chen for more details.

Last but not least, you can do forward declarations just with the real structure name; and if you don't have a structure name (but just the `typedef`) you cannot do forward declarations.

Comment: Huh? Since when does the linker know about type names at all?

Comment: @R.: you're right, I think I wrote that because I'm used to the linker errors in C++, where the linker refer to the *type* of the class to which the faulty method belongs (even if those types are just the result of demangling the method names).

Answer (score 2):

The authors may not know that you can (or don't prefer to) omit the `someobj`.  If you want only one way to refer to the type, then you can write:

```
typedef struct {
  ...
} someobj_t;
```

As Kos mentions in another answer, this is fine as long as the structure doesn't need to refer to itself (e.g. in a linked list).  For maximum confusion, you could always do:

```
typedef struct someobj_t {
  ...
} someobj_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
typedef struct someobj {
 ... stuff ...
} someobj_t;
```

This allows you to use `someobj_`t as a type instead of `struct someobj`. Both notations are equivalent.